# How to change the opacity background color of other two buttons once we click on a single button using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am having three buttons if i click on one button the other two buttons background color opacity should be 40% .In the same way it should change accordingly while clicking on other buttons.Thanks In Advance. [Here is my jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gsoLuf57/)

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback ng-scope">                      
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn- newbutton7"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;margin-left:-4px;">Annual Compensation</strong></a>
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn- newbutton8"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;">Monthly Payslips</strong></a>
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn- newbutton9"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;margin-left:-8px;">Investment</strong></a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn.btn-.newbutton7{

width: 197px;
height: 41px;
margin-top: 56px;

background-color:#01cd27;
color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
}
.btn.btn-.newbutton8{    
width: 197px;
height: 41px;
margin-top: 56px;   
background-color:#f8b100;
color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
}
.btn.btn-.newbutton9{    
width: 197px;
height: 41px;
margin-top: -64px;    
background-color:#6b01cd;
color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/gsoLuf57/

Comment: Solution with or with out jQuerry?

Comment: with jquery also without also no issues

Comment: Should elements have default `opacity` of `40%` when no elements have been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following jquery code:

```
$('.has-feedback a').click(function(){
$(this).css('opacity',1);
$('.has-feedback a').not(this).css('opacity',0.4);
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xd17xyrm/

or:

css:

```
.opacty {
  opacity:0.4;
}
```

js:

```
$('.has-feedback a').not('.has-feedback a:first').addClass('opacty');

$('.has-feedback a').click(function(e){
$('.has-feedback a').not(this).addClass('opacty');
 $(this).removeClass('opacty');

});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xd17xyrm/1/

Comment: Once i open the default second and third button opacity should be 40% and if select second button first and third button opacity should be 40%.

Comment: what problem did you encountered?

Comment: do you have jquery added to your page?, as you can see in my jsfiddle is working

Answer (score 0):

try the following working code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("body").on("click", ".has-feedback a", function() 
        {
            $('.has-feedback a').css('opacity',0.5);
            $(this).css('opacity',1);
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="form-group has-feedback ng-scope">                      
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn- newbutton7"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;margin-left:-4px;">Annual Compensation</strong></a>
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn- newbutton8"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;">Monthly Payslips</strong></a>
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn- newbutton9"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;margin-left:-8px;">Investment</strong></a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS Free** version working the same way like JS or jQuery Solutions but also with blocked JS.

JS-Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/of20L8do/

CSS

```
.btn.btn-.newbutton7{

width: 197px;
height: 41px;
margin-top: 56px;

background-color:#01cd27;
color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
}
.btn.btn-.newbutton8{    
width: 197px;
height: 41px;
margin-top: 56px;   
background-color:#f8b100;
color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
}
.btn.btn-.newbutton9{    
width: 197px;
height: 41px;
margin-top: -64px;    
background-color:#6b01cd;
color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
}
.has-feedback input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.has-feedback input[type=radio] + a {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.has-feedback input[type=radio]:checked + a {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.has-feedback input[value=default]:checked + span a {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback ng-scope">                      
 <input type="radio" name="bnt" value="default" checked="checked">
 <span>
   <label><input type="radio" name="bnt" ><a class="btn btn- newbutton7"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;margin-left:-4px;">Annual Compensation</strong></a></label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="bnt" ><a class="btn btn- newbutton8"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;">Monthly Payslips</strong></a></label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="bnt" ><a class="btn btn- newbutton9"><strong style="text-align:center;font-size:17px;font-family: sans-serif;margin-left:-8px;">Investment</strong></a></label>
 </span>
</div>
```